# Remove all the occurrences of a word except the third and second last occurrence using sed

Tags: text-processing, sed, command-line

I am trying to Remove all the occurrences of a word except the third and second last occurrence using sed
for example if input is :

```
1 liam
2 liam
3 liam
4 liam
5 liam
6 liam
```

Output should be:

```
1
2
3 liam
4
5 liam
6
```

Comment: Is the word always a word or can it be a substring (e.g. mil**liam**pere)? Is the word always the second word on each line or can it apear anywhere on the line? Can there be more than one occurrence of the word on the same line and, if so, how should we deal with it?

Comment: Even more questions in @terdon's vein: Is there a minimum number of occurrences (e.g. 5, because if you have less there's not enough space to have both a separate third and second-to-last "liam")? Can you exclusively only use `sed` or are other (basic) cli tools available? Is using solely a different tool other than `sed` an option?

Answer (score 1):

thus can be handled with awk if that's an option. We set the filed  separator to the word you want to replace with. Assuming there are no regex characters in it. Then set the record separator to empty regex and loop over the fields. Substitute the field separator back in the 3rd and third last.

```
$ awk -F 'liam' '
{
 for (i=1;i<NF-1; i++) {
   if (i==3||i==NF-2) {
     sub(/$/, FS, $i)
   }
 }
}
1' RS='^$' OFS= file
```

Comment: This is really clever (+1)! But do note that it requires loading the entire file in memory. This is unavoidable, if course, since the OP needs to find the penultimate occurrence, so you either need to process the file twice or load it into memory, but it still should be pointed out in case the input is huge.

Comment: Don't agree with you, @terdon: The usual "trick" to handle "n-th from the end" without knowing how many entries there are, is to reverse the input (in this case, the file) and work on the "n-th" (in this case, the second entry). Still, you need a bit more of information about the number of entries (to account for edge cases in low-number situations).

Comment: @NicApicella reversing the file will make it easy to find the penultimate, but then you would have the same problem when trying to find the 3rd (which is now the 3rd-to-last). I don't see how it is possible to get both the 3rd _and_ the penultimate without either storing in memory or reading the file twice.